# I do not understand the alternative definition of derivative and how to use it to find tangent slope.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the slope of the tangent line at $x=3$ for $|2x-6|$

The alternative definition of derivative is $$f(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

If I want to find the derivative at $3$. I would plug $3$ into $c$.

This results in: $$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{|2x-6|-0}{x-3}$$

This answer results in $0/0$ because it is a sharp turn.

I want to find the tangent slope of points around it to prove it is a sharp turn. I am going to find the tangent slope at $2.9$ and $3.1$. How come it works if I plug in $2.9$ and $3.1$ into $x$?

$$\frac{|2(2.9)-6|-0}{2.9-3}=-2$$
$$\frac{|2(3.1)-6|-0}{3.1-3}=2$$

I check desmos and both of the slope is correct. My question is why? The formula of the derivative is $$f(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$ To find the tangent slope, I should do $$f(2.9)=\lim_{x\to 2.9}\frac{f(x)-f(2.9)}{x-2.9}$$

$$f(2.9)=-.2$$
$$f(2.9)=\lim_{x\to 2.9}\frac{|2(x)-6|-.2}{x-2.9}$$
$$f(2.9)=\lim_{x\to 2.9}\frac{|2(2.9)-6|-.2}{2.9-2.9}=0$$

Why does the first way work, but not the second? Why does the second method answer indicate a sharp turn.

I was watching the youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rowIURKDnag&index=5&list=PLRWGJgOxXM4T2ZOuFMxtdKqiKra2_BLKY. I do not understand how she did the problem at time stamp 12:08.

Comment: Are you dealing with $|2x+6|$ (first line) or $|2x-6|$ (down in your post)?

Comment: Perhaps you should sketch the function from which you will see that it has a constant slope near $x=3$. Putting $x=2.9$ in the calculation at the end does not give you $0$, but $\frac 00$ - you need to evaluate the limit and you can't do that by substituting a value. Also the definition is of $f'(c)$ not $f(c)$ and there are various other typos and inconsistencies. Your question needs a thorough edit for accuracy, and if you do this with care i may help you to understand.

Comment: @TonyHuang Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

> This results in: $$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\lvert 2x-6\rvert - 0}{x-3}$$
>
> This answer results in $0/0$ because it is a sharp turn.

No, actually it is *not* "because it is a sharp turn."

The only way you can get $\frac00$ out of
$\frac{\lvert 2x-6\rvert-0}{x-3}$ is if
you simply substitute $x = 3.$
At that point, the fact that $\lvert 2x-6\rvert$ has a "sharp turn" is completely irrelevant.
If you try to find derivatives this way, by simply setting $x$ to the same value as $c$ in the definition, you will *always* get $\frac00$,
because $f(c) - f(c) = 0$ and $c - c = 0.$
This will happen with *any* function $f$, even a nice one such as
$f(x) = x^2$ or even a constant function such as $f(x) = 5.$

Let's try this graphically.
When $x \neq c,$ the expression
$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
gives you the slope of the unique line through the two points
$(x,f(x))$ and $(c,f(c))$ on the graph of $y = f(x).$
This is called a secant line because it goes through two distinct points of the function's graph, like a secant through two points on a circle.
The idea of the "limit" in the definition
$$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
is that we can force the slope of the secant line to be as close to the true "tangent" slope at $(c,f(c))$ as we can possibly want, just by putting a restriction on $x$ that it must be within a certain neighborhood around $c.$
(A "neighborhood" is always the set of all points within some distance of $c,$ not including $c$ itself.)

But for your particular example, where $f(x) = \lvert 2x-6\rvert,$
what you find when you set $x = 2.9$ is the same result you will find when you set $x$ to any value less than $3.$ The slope of the secant line is $-2.$
What you find when you set $x = 3.1$ is the same result you will find when you set $x$ to any value greater than $3.$ The slope is $2.$

So no matter how tightly you restrict the neighborhood around $c=3,$
you'll always have secant lines with slope $-2$ and others with slope $2.$
Hence you never get a single limit value, hence no limit,
hence no derivative.

If you actually evaluate the derivative at $c = 2.9$ or $c = 3.1,$
or any value other than $c= 3,$
what you will find is that the derivative is always $-2$ when $c < 3$
and always $2$ when $c > 3.$
This is your "sharp corner," and it is true that a function with a "sharp corner" will not have a derivative at that point.
But that's not because of some $\frac00$ calculation,
it's because you cannot get the secants for $x < c$ to converge together with the secants for $x > c$ to the same real number.

Comment: So let me get this straight. The reason why one can't find the derivative at a sharp turn is not because of 0/0, but because the limit part of the derivative formula fails. The definition of a limit is the value that a function approaches.  The derivative formula finds the slope as x approaches c from the left side and the right side. The limit then checks if the slope approaches the same number and that the slope exists. The limit x-> c+ and x-> c- cannot be different, which is the slope (sharp turns. Also the limit x->c+ and x->c- cannot be undefined, which is vertical tangent.

Comment: |2(2.9)−6|−02.9−3=−2
 
|2(3.1)−6|−03.1−3=2

Comment: I think you got it. You have enumerated the ways a "sharp corner" prevents the existence of a derivative: left-side and right-side limits are different finite numbers, or one or both are infinite. I think that covers all the cases we would consider to be "sharp corners." There are also points on continuous functions where the derivative fails because the function "wiggles" an infinite number of times (so even the one-sided limit is neither a finite number nor infinite), but I think we would not call that a "sharp corner."

Answer (score 0):

Yes by the definition the derivative at that point is given by the limit

$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{|2x-6|-0}{x-3}$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{|2x-6|-0}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{2(x-3)}{x-3}=2\neq \lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{|2x-6|-0}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{-2(x-3)}{x-3}=-2$$

and therefore the function is not differentiable at $x=3$ since the given limit doesn't exist at that point.